# How to backup Vm instance Google cloud

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql

We have created 3 VM instance and hosted our website on this.

We want to backup of all the database and website and folder and follow the step given at below below link.

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/backup-recovery

We have scheduled the backup ,but no backup showing in Google developer console.
http://prntscr.com/69y52p

Kindly advice us how to schedule backup of all hosted VM in Google cloud.

Comment: Has the backup been made? could you put the output of the command:  `gcloud sql instances describe INSTANCE_NAME`? You'll need to install the [Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/).

Comment: Dear  Adrián i enable backup from Google admin console ,kindly see the out of command gcloud sql instances describe INSTANCE_NAME.     
Kindly see the below link for above command out.http://prntscr.com/6asn1w

Comment: Could you please attach results of "gcloud sql operations list -i INSTANCE_NAME" ?

Comment: Dear Paolo,kindly find the output of gcloud opearations list -i INSTANCE_NAME in below link.http://prntscr.com/6atzeb

Comment: Thank you, so last backup seems to have been done on Dec 20th. Is blog currently being used so content is changing? Could you please run "gcloud sql backups list -i wordpress"

Comment: Dear Paolo P,
Kindly find the output of gcloud sql backups list -i wordpress in below link.
http://prntscr.com/6bnvhy
As i have enable Backup of instance from Google admin console ,for every day see in the below link.
Why it is not taking every day.
http://prntscr.com/6bnvuv

Comment: As stated at [the CloudSQL documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/backup-recovery#backups) _Google Cloud SQL takes a backup of an instance only if the instance's data has changed since the last backup_ . 
Could it be possible that the data hasn't changed since 20th Dec? Does it make sense for you?

Comment: @technical if you have resolved your issue can you post the solution as an answer and accept it. This will help other users with the similar issue looking for a solution. Thanks

Comment: This question has been answered on [this thread](http://serverfault.com/questions/671808/google-cloud-sql-backups-are-not-running) as well.

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud SQL will skip doing a backup if it knows that no backup is needed. The backup of an instance is taken only if instance's data has changed since the last backup. This information is documented on [CloudSQL Overview of Backups page](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/backup-recovery/backups#backups).